# Retrieving MY iOS app's files from the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

Recently, I accidentally overwrote my iOS app on my Mac. But I uploaded to Apple Connect for testing. Is there a way to retrieve the files of my app from there?

Comment: At best you can only extract your Info.plist and some bundle resources. No code. This is why you use source code control and Time Machine (or some other backup). You did use some form of backup, right?

Comment: @rmaddy unfortunately I did not.

Answer (score 1):

No. What you uploaded to App Store Connect is compiled code. What you are looking for is your source code (text).

Comment: that is correct. I'm looking for the source code.

Comment: Right, well, Apple doesn't have it. And that is what you asked.